# Changing the value to negative

Tags: nodes

I have a content type of invoice. This also has a drop down list (list text) to let the user pick one of three types - receivable , payable and proforma.

I also have it so I'm getting the amount, vat and total of the invoice.

However, what I need to do is change the value of the invoice amount, vat, and total when the user picks payable from the drop down menu to a negative value. For example, I fill out the invoice make it payable and I enter 2000 in the amount, 230 in vat and 2300 in total fields. I need these values to become negative when I run aggregator plus on them so instead of adding these numbers it subtracts them instead.

I was wondering if I can do this using rules, or do I create a new module to do this, or if I add a function to the template.php file. Any ideas of what is easiest and best

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most elegant solution would be to leave the original values and to define how you operate with them (adding, substracting, etc.) at the [Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) level, but I am not familiar with that module, and I don't know how easy it would be to extend it.

If you want to modify the value of these fields before saving the node, there are at least two possibilities I can think of:

- Using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) (it involves creating some custom PHP code). The following example (using increment instead of changing the sign) can give you a hint: https://www.drupal.org/node/1389074
- Creating a custom module and implementing [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7), in order to modify the fields before they are written to the database.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

use [rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), condition: entity_has_field[yournumericfield], condition: [yournumericfield] > 0 (ensure is not already negative), actions: calculate_a_value, [yournumericfield] x [-1] , variablename=my_new_negative_value, action:set_a_data_value, [yournumericfield]=my_new_negative_value, action:save_entity.

be sure to set a low rule_weight to ensure this rule runs before other rules involved.

footnote:  multiply any number by -1 changes number sign